# Is there a easy way to convert this in R using dplyr?

Tags: r, string, dplyr, numeric, survey

I have this data with Five column names: ID, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, and Q5.

| ID | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Q4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | (2) important | (3) very important | (1) No imporant | (1) No imporant |
| 102 | (3) very important | (2) important | (2) important | (3) very important |
| 103 | (1) No imporant | (1) No imporant | (3) very important | (2) important |
| 104 | (2) important | (3) very important | (1) No imporant | (1) No imporant |
| 105 | (3) very important | (2) important | (2) important | (3) very important |
| 106 | (1) No imporant | (1) No imporant | (3) very important | (2) important |
| 107 | (2) important | (3) very important | (1) No imporant | (1) No imporant |
| 108 | (3) very important | (2) important | (2) important | (3) very important |
| 109 | (1) No imporant | (1) No imporant | (3) very important | (2) important |
| 110 | (2) important | (3) very important | (1) No imporant | (1) No imporant |

I want to convert it to this:

| ID | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Q4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 102 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 103 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 104 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 105 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 106 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 107 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 108 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 109 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 110 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: Please make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) or [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with a sample input (not posted in an image) and your expected output. This is needed to create, test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 3):

If your dataset is `data`, you can do this, using `dplyr::mutate(across())` and `stringr::str_extract()`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

data %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("Q"),~str_extract(.x,"\\d")))
```

Output:

```
      ID     Q1     Q2     Q3     Q4
   <num> <char> <char> <char> <char>
1:   101      2      3      1      1
2:   102      3      2      2      3
3:   103      1      1      3      2
```

Comment: Error in across(starts_with("Q"), ~str_extract(.x, "\\d")) : 
  could not find function "across".

Comment: I am getting this error.

Comment: you may have quite an old version of `dplyr`. You can try the now superseded `mutate_at()` if you like: `data %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Q")),~str_extract(.x,"\\d"))`

Comment: You are right. I was using the old verison of dplyr. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect use case for `parse_number` from `readr` package:

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(-ID, ~parse_number(.)))
```

```
    ID Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4
1  101  2  3  1  1
2  102  3  2  2  3
3  103  1  1  3  2
4  104  2  3  1  1
5  105  3  2  2  3
6  106  1  1  3  2
7  107  2  3  1  1
8  108  3  2  2  3
9  109  1  1  3  2
10 110  2  3  1  1
```

data:

```
structure(list(ID = 101:110, Q1 = c("(2) important", "(3) very important", 
"(1) No imporant", "(2) important", "(3) very important", "(1) No imporant", 
"(2) important", "(3) very important", "(1) No imporant", "(2) important"
), Q2 = c("(3) very important", "(2) important", "(1) No imporant", 
"(3) very important", "(2) important", "(1) No imporant", "(3) very important", 
"(2) important", "(1) No imporant", "(3) very important"), Q3 = c("(1) No imporant", 
"(2) important", "(3) very important", "(1) No imporant", "(2) important", 
"(3) very important", "(1) No imporant", "(2) important", "(3) very important", 
"(1) No imporant"), Q4 = c("(1) No imporant", "(3) very important", 
"(2) important", "(1) No imporant", "(3) very important", "(2) important", 
"(1) No imporant", "(3) very important", "(2) important", "(1) No imporant"
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you but I am getting this error:  Error in across(-ID, ~parse_number(.)) : could not find function "across"

Comment: Use `library(dplyr)` . dplyr 1.0.8